# DataGrid View creation via ForEach

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I am having an issue extracting the value from every row in column "MobileID" within a table named "dt" that is within a dataset named "ds".

Here is how the dataset and datatable are created.

```
        Public Function GetClientSpecificDevices(ByVal argHost As FOO.BAR.SHOO, ByVal currentClientIDSelection As Integer) As DataSet        
        Return argHost.GetDataSet("SELECT MobileID FROM mobiledevices WHERE ClientID = " & currentClientIDSelection & ";")

        'create dataset to handle tabular data
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        'Ensure every call refreshes dataset rather than appending
        'ds.Tables.Clear()
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        'add table and populate table with data
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        dt.Columns.Add("MobileID")
        'return dataset
        Return ds
```

And for the DataGrid

```
Function GenerateDataRows() As Object
    Dim row As New DataGridViewRow()
    Dim ds As DataSet = GetClientSpecificDevices(_objHost, CInt(comboBox_clients.ValueMember))
    If Not ds Is Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each A As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            'populate rows
            Dim deviceID As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
            Dim deviceName As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
            Dim deviceModel As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
            Dim devicePhoneNum As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
        Next
    End If

    Return row
End Function
```

I'm looking for something like this

```
Dim deviceID As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
deviceID.Value  = A.MobileID
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Solution was found.

MobileID is not a property but rather a column.

So it seems that

    deviceID.Value = A("MobileID")

Should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are creating a separate DataGridViewTextBoxCell which is not cooperating with your DataGridViewRow, you may try the following code

```
Function GenerateDataRows() As Object
    Dim row As New DataGridViewRow()
    Dim ds As DataSet = GetClientSpecificDevices(_objHost, CInt(comboBox_clients.ValueMember))
    If Not ds Is Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each A As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            'populate rows
           row.cell(0).value = A.MobileID
        Next
    End If

    Return row
End Function
```